# We've missed the 10 year anniversary (understandable since well, COVID) but there's still things we can do?

Tags: discussion

According to the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/c/moderators/questions/3644) on Stack Moderators about celebrating the 10th anniversary of the community, the way to determine the age of the site is:

> How to determine the age of a site? We agreed to calculate the age by
> the date of the first question on the site. This is a
> one-size-fits-all approach that works for all communities.
>
> In order to determine the age of your community, please go to the
> first question on your site (yoursitename.com/questions/1). For
> example, https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/1/

So if you follow the instructions, this is the question that you will end up with:

[Are radial contextual menus better than vertical list menus?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1)

[image]

Which as you can see if you look at the question that it was asked 10 years, 6 months ago.

So we may have missed our 10th anniversary because we were still trying to deal with COVID and all the disruptions caused by the pandemic last year, but hopefully there's still something we can do to celebrate the occasion.

Updates to follow...

Comment: There's a question from 2008 if you use the pager to find the oldest... was it migrated, perhaps? https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/8238/is-microsofts-ribbon-ui-really-that-great-from-a-usability-perspective